# Package pinning in Debian lenny

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, debian-lenny, pinning

I need your advice as I don't know if I hit a bug, or I am misunderstanding something.

**On a Debian Lenny, I am trying to prevent the installation of two particular packages**, when they are requested as dependencies fromother packages. **I am using the same syntax I successfully used in Squeeze, but with no success at all**.

On squeeze, the following works as expected:

```
# cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/local-no-pike.pref
Package: pike7.6-core
Pin: version *
Pin-Priority: -1000
```

If I try to install `pike7.6`, which depends on `pike7.6-core`, *apt* and *aptitude* refuse to do so.

On Lenny, the only difference is that there is no support for "fragments" in `/etc/apt/preferences.d`, and all preferences must be in the `/etc/apt/preferences` file. But it's not working. E.g., if the file contains:

```
Package: grub-common
Pin: version *
Pin-Priority: -1000
```

*apt* doesn't stop me from installing `grub`, which depends on `grub-common`.

**I used `strace`** to see if the file is being read, and it is. I was suggested to use **some `Debug::` options**, but they didn't help to pinpoint the problem either. I have **google'd a lot** with some combinations of "*lenny*" "*prevent*" "*package*" "*installation*" "*pinning*" and the like, but nothing nice came out. And of course **I read `man apt_preferences`**.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe it's simply that the algorithm for pinning is flawed in Lenny?  [look at the very last list point](http://carlo17.home.xs4all.nl/howto/debian.html#errata)

Answer (score 1):

as a workaround you can prevent a package upgrade by setting it to "hold" in dpkg:

```
echo "grub-common hold"|dpkg --set-selections
```

then you can revert this with

```
echo "grub-common install"|dpkg --set-selections
```

another option mentioned here: http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2009/07/msg00477.html

```
Package: somepackage
Pin: release a=fakerepo
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

> Since "fakerepo" is not a valid release, "somepackage" is never installable.

also may be helpful to check "apt-cache policy grub-common" output

Comment: Tried already, didn't work

Comment: I added another option, which I never tried...

Comment: I had tried with apt-cache policy, but could not get anything useful out of it; it really seems that the pinning algorithm is flawed in lenny, and it was fixed in squeeze.
As for the fakerepo, I had not tried it. Not sure I can, since we had to implement a different solution due to time constraints

Comment: as I understand you don't need to setup a fake repo, only configure some garbage on the "Pin: release a=xxX" line

Comment: That was understood :) But we had to work around the problem another way, so I am not sure I'll manage to test with a fakerepo-style line. However, I'll save the suggestion, you never know :) Thanks